# Laravel separate folder Frontend and Backend

Tags: php, laravel, api, frontend, backend

i want to build laravel project, and i want to separate between web and app.

i have 2 folder

folder 1:

FrontEnd

```
-- App
--Bootstrap
--Config
--resources
-- ETC
```

folder 2:

Backend

```
-- App
--Bootstrap
--Config
--resources
-- ETC
```

the question is:

- how to comunicate between 2 folder? what is the best method or package?

i am new in laravel

thanks in advance

Comment: You can run one as a subdomain, with the subdomain in a separate folder completely. Or if there's going to be a lot of crossover, then just use one Laravel installation, and use the `group` route function for ease of route programming. `Route::group('backend', function() { // more routes });`

Comment: Besides that you can just put your backend models and controllers in subfolders called "Backend" and add the backend namespace to it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to share the frontend and the backend, there is a folder in laravel resource -> view it contains all of your templates.

Comment: yes i know it, but i want to make it like 3 tier architecture (web-app-database), so i must separate between front and back

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i'm not understanding you well but i don't find necessary to put two applications in a same folder. Either you create two projects or you mix both.
And to mix them, what you can do is create to separated folders in `ressources/views` named **frontend** and **backend**.
At the level on te routes, you can create a route group to manage this.
By this way, the application will communicated as you want